# PowerPoint programmatically add and remove metadata?

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, powerpoint

I'm wondering if it's possible to store metadata in PowerPoint files using C#? It should be able to store a reasonably large amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure ... should be possible with C# or any other language that can automate PowerPoint.

Every presentation, slide and shape has a `.Tags` collection (*name/value pairs of strings*) that can hold pretty much as much data as you want to pour in.  When I tested this long ago, I found that relatively few tags holding lots of data each was more efficient than huge numbers of tags each with small bits of data.  This was with 1 to 1.5 megabytes of string data.

As of PPT 2007 or so, there's a programmatic interface to binary tags also, but I've never used them so can't give much advice.

I would *DEFINITELY* avoid storing much data as document properties.  Overloading doc props can have unwanted side effects on links.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, what constitutes much data? I'm assuming something like a 10MB limit is reasonable?